# Sums and Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: analysis

I am reading a proof form my analysis class where it looks like they say 
$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k a_{n-k}\right|^2 \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}|a_k|^2*|a_{n-k}|^2$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. However i do not see how this is true, as Cauchy-Schwarz gives $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k a_{n-k}\right|^2 \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}|a_k|^2*\sum_{k=0}^{n}|a_{n-k}|^2 $. I would be very thankfull if someone could show way this is true, or if not show why it is false.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz...please write clean.

Comment: Suppose $a_k=1$ for all $k$. Then $(n+1)^2\le(n+1)$ is false for $n>0$.

Comment: It was almost certainly meant to say $|\sum_ka_ka_{n-k}|^2\le\sum_k|a_k|^2\sum_k|a_{n-k}|^2$.